# TableView insertSection calling ViewForHeaderInsection too many times

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am finding that when I use `tableView.insertSection` instead of `tableView.reloadData`, my UI freezes longer during scrolling. To test out what was wrong, I have implemented a counter that increments everytime I entered `viewForHeaderInSection`. The counter is reset to 0 just before I call the `insertSection` or `reloadData` method. Basically my app loads five more posts onto the table when the user reached the bottom of the tableView. Below are the code and result.

Inside my `viewForHeaderInSection`, I configure the cell to display images, data

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    enterCount += 1
    // configure cell
}


Method 1: 
enterCount = 0
for post in downloadedPostArray {
    downloadedPostArray.append(post)
    let sections = NSIndexSet(index: myPosts.count - 1)
    myTableView.insertSections(sections, withRowAnimation: .None)
}

Method 2: 
enterCount = 0
for post in downloadedPostArray {
    downloadedPostArray.append(post)
}
myTableView.reloadData()
```

Result for `method 2`,

Upon first launch, the counter goes from 1 to 2. Because only 2 sections are available
As I scroll down, the number increases to 8 then I hit the `loadMoreFunction` which resets the `counter` back to 0. 
Then if I scroll down more, the steps above repeats where the counter goes from 1 to 8 consistently. (As expected)

Weird result for method 1,

Upon first launch, the counter goes from 1 to 10. 
As I scroll down, the screen freezes and the counter goes from 1 to 33.
As I scroll down more, the screen freezes longer and the counter goes from 1 to 53.

And the more I scroll, the higher the number goes. I understand why the screen freezes because it is trying to configure the `ViewForHeaderInSection` so many times.

I want to implement infinite scrolling by inserting rows without `viewForHeaderInSection` getting called so many times freezing my `UI`. Ideally, it should really be called minimal amout of times so I have a smooth `UI`.

Comment: Why are you inserting sections?  Why not insert rows into the existing section?

Comment: Section is what I am inserting because they are custom headers with images. The rows are displaying some other data relating to the section header.

Comment: You could try saving your header views in an array or dictionary so that you can return them quickly when you are asked for them a second time, but it really sounds like you should have different cell types; one for the information you are displaying in the section header and one for the other type of data

Comment: I am more trying to find out if there is a way to insertSection without having viewForHeaderInSection being called so many times (That is like calling reloadData multiple times when you just want to reload once).  My section header is like in Instagram where the table displays username, image, buttons. And my rows are displaying top comments. I am open to different ways of doing it if you could point me to the right direction?

Comment: I suspect that whatever you are doing is causing the table to be relaid out multiple times. As I suggested, you could use different cell types in a single section.